# Testing DaVinci Resolve on the cloud

Tags: davinci-resolve

My computer is too old to run DaVinci Resolve, which hangs upon installing. I want to try the Chroma key feature of DaVinci and found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sethgoldin/a-cloud-dailies-supercomputer-workflow-rendering-via-davinci-resolve-on-an-aws-p3dn-24xlarge-a82c92f18d33) for launching a AWS EC2 instance running CentOS and installing DaVinci, TigerVNC, connecting to S3, etc. It seems too complicated for what I want, which is simply upload a clip, chroma key the green screen, and export. [This case study](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/creating-a-feature-film-with-davinci-resolve-on-aws/) sets up cloud post-production for a feature film and seems even more complicated.

What is the easiest way to test DaVinci Resolve on the cloud, with any cloud provider?

Comment: You might be better off using a dedicated command line program like ffmpeg if you want to do it in the cloud.

Comment: I already use FFMPEG command-line on a Pine64 micro-computer. I do want to test DaVinci Resolve in particular.

Comment: Cloud setups for Resolve are no joke.  The admins and support staff on the BMD support forums regularly advise against it, and as Seth’s article points out, the devs seem to go out of their way to make it difficult, for whatever reason.  Maybe it’s hard to police the licenses?

Comment: Seth Goldin and others discuss it more here https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?t=119546

Comment: Actually before starting all the mess for the cloud, I'd get  a new computer (the cloud to take with you all the time ;-))

Answer (score 2):

I would find a cloud provider that can offer full VNC access to dedicated hardware... Even so, your experience is going to be pretty unpleasant unless you've got a really fast connection. Latency is going to make it really fiddly to go frame by frame, and most VNC connections reduce the colour depth to a point where it's hard to tell what's going on.  I guess you can render and look at shots, but it's going to be laborious.

Comment: I should add - I've never actually tried Resolve over a VNC.  But I have tried to use Blender over one, and it was no fun... (except for the lack of fan noise when rendering - and the speed).